# What are the uses of inner classes in Java? Are nested classes and inner classes the same?

Tags: java, inner-classes

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Java inner class and static nested class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70324/java-inner-class-and-static-nested-class)

What are the uses of inner classes in Java? Are nested classes and inner classes the same?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No, they're not the same: an inner class is non-`static`.

> #### [JLS 8.1.3 Inner Classes and Enclosing Instances](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/#8.1.3)
>
> An *inner* class is a nested class that is not explicitly or implicitly declared static.

Consult also the following diagram from Joe Darcy:

> #### [Joseph D. Darcy's Oracle Weblog - Nested, Inner, Member, and Top-Level Classes](https://blogs.oracle.com/darcy/nested,-inner,-member,-and-top-level-classes)
>
> [image]

---

#### Related questions

- [Java inner class and static nested class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70324/java-inner-class-and-static-nested-class)

Answer (score 15):

The difference is well addressed by the other answer. Regarding their usage/relevance, here is my view:

#### Anonymous class: handy for **productivity**

They are handy to implement callbacks easily, without the burden to create new *named* class.

```
button.addActionListener(
      new ActionListener() {
         public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent e ) {
              frame.dispose();
         }
      }
);
```

They are also handy for threading (e.g. anonymous `Runnable`) and a few other similar pattern.

#### Static nested class: handy for **encapsulation**

Static nested classes are essentially like regular classes, except that their name is `OuterClass.StaticNestedClass` and you can play with modifier. So it provided some form of encapsulation that can not exactly be achieved with top-level classes.

Think for instance of a `LinkedList` for which you would like the class `Node` (used only internally) to not be visible in the package view. Make it a static nested class so that it's fully internal to the `LinkedList`.

#### Inner class: handy for **ownership** and **encapsulation**

An *instance* of an inner class has access to the field of its enclosing class *instance*. Think again of the linked list and imagine `Node` is an inner class:

```
public class LinkedList {
  private Node root = null;

  public class Node {
    private Object obj;
    private Node next;

    ...

    public void setAsRoot() {
       root = this;
    }
  }

  public Node getRoot() {
    return root;
  }

  public void setRoot( Node node ) {
    root = node;
  }

}
```

Each `Node` instance belonging to a `LinkedList` can access it directly. There is an implicit **ownership relationship** between the list and its nodes; the list owns its nodes. The same ownership relationship would require extra code if implemented with regular classes.

See [Achieve better Java code with inner and anonymous classes](https://web.archive.org/web/1/http://articles.techrepublic%2ecom%2ecom/5100-10878_11-5035155.html)

Comment: I like this answer, coming from a .net world to a world where no delegates exists, inner classes can prove useful...