# What is the purpose of nested classes in Java?

Tags: java, inner-classes, nested-class

I've seen this sample code from [Oracle Website](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html#shadowing) about Java ?

```
public class Parent {
    class InnerClass {
        void methodInFirstLevel(int x) {
           // some code
        }
    }

    public static void main(String... args) {
        Parent parent = new Parent();
        Parent.InnerClass inner = parent.new InnerClass();
    }
}
```

- What is the purpose of the construct `parent.new InnerClass()`?
- What kind of classes would be suited to such construction?

**The title may be misleading**: I understand everything about this construct.

**I just don't understand where and when to use this Java feature.**

I found another syntax to do the same: [Java: Non-static nested classes and instance.super()](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2831484/251745)

There are lot's of references about this structure, but nothing about the application.

[References]

- [Java inner class and static nested class](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70324/251745)
- [Java: Static vs non static inner class [duplicate]](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1353309/251745)
- [what is the use of inner classes in java ? is nested classes and inner classes are same? [duplicate]](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2941682/251745)
- [Java: Static vs non static inner class [duplicate]](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1353309/251745)

Comment: One good use is a static inner class named `Builder` for the Builder design pattern...

Comment: The official Java tutorial covers them: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html

Comment: Not specific for Java 8, has existed probably since the first Java version

Comment: @JBNizet That is the page he is linking to.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel: Since Java 1.2, IIRC.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel: Oh, yes indeed. There's a "Why use nested classes" section in the page. Not sure how an answer could explain what several pages of the tutorial can't.

Comment: @JBNizet Seems to be down the middle in version 1.1 :) http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inner_class#Programming_languages

Comment: @BalusC I have tested this snippet on JDK6, and it does not compile. For me it's working since Java 7... Any info ?

Answer (score 2):

> What is the purpose of `parent.new InnerClass()`?

This is for demonstration - using this mechanism to construct an inner class is rare. Normally inner classes are created only by the outer class when it is just created with `new InnerClass()` as usual.

> What kind of classes would be suited to such construction?

Look at `Map.Entry<K,V>` for a classic example. Here you can see an inner class called `Entry` that should be created by all classes that implement `Map`.

Comment: The structure provided in the sample require to create an instance of `Parent` before create an instance of `InnerClass`. I do not understand the link with Map.Entry ?

Comment: @chepseskaf - for non-static inner classes, each one has a connection to its parent so that it can access the parent's fields and methods so a parent **must** already exist for each child to attach to. It makes sense to enclosed the `Entry` class in the `Map` class because each type of `Map` is likely to have have different kinds of `Entry`.

Comment: I'm next to @chepseskaf and we fully undestand what an inner non-static class is and its relation to its parent. What we can not figure out is why would somebody instanciate a Parent and then __need to__ instanciate an InnerClass from the Parent instance. This is very different from the Map.Entry example. What use case would need such a technic?

Comment: @Pigelvy - For demonstration mostly. I do not recall ever needing to do it this way in real life.

Answer (score 1):

I see many answers here explaining the use of inner classes, but as far as I can see, the question is about the specific construct `parent.new InnerClass()`.

The reason for that syntax is very simple: an instance of an inner class must belong to an *instance* of the surrounding class. But since `main` is a static method, there is no surrounding `Parent` object. Therefore, you must explicitly specify that object.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // this results in an error:
    // no enclosing instance of type Parent is available
    InnterClass inner = new InnerClass();

    // this works because you specify the surrounding object
    Parent parent = new Parent();
    InnerClass inner = parent.new InnerClass();     
}
```

I'm searching for a use of this construct in the standard packages, but so far I haven't found an example.

Comment: You seem to understand the question but your answer is all about the technic itself, not the pertinence/usage of this technic.

Comment: @Pigelvy you are right. The reason is that I don't see a use for this syntax. Every example I come up with can be solved easier without it...

Answer (score 0):

Inner classes nest within other classes. A normal class is a direct member of a package, a top-level class. Inner classes, which became available with Java 1.1, come in four flavors:

- Static member classes
- Member classes
- Local classes
- Anonymous classes

the most important feature of the inner class is that it allows you to turn things into objects that you normally wouldn't turn into objects. That allows your code to be even more object-oriented than it would be without inner classes.

```
public class DataStructure {
    // create an array
    private final static int SIZE = 15;
    private int[] arrayOfInts = new int[SIZE];

    public DataStructure() {
        // fill the array with ascending integer values
        for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
            arrayOfInts[i] = i;
        }
    }

    public void printEven() {
        // print out values of even indices of the array
        InnerEvenIterator iterator = this.new InnerEvenIterator();
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            System.out.println(iterator.getNext() + " ");
        }
    }

    // inner class implements the Iterator pattern
    private class InnerEvenIterator {
        // start stepping through the array from the beginning
        private int next = 0;

        public boolean hasNext() {
            // check if a current element is the last in the array
            return (next <= SIZE - 1);
        }

        public int getNext() {
            // record a value of an even index of the array
            int retValue = arrayOfInts[next];
            //get the next even element
            next += 2;
            return retValue;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String s[]) {
        // fill the array with integer values and print out only
        // values of even indices
        DataStructure ds = new DataStructure();
        ds.printEven();
    }
}
```

Comment: This sentence "allows you to turn things into objects that you normally wouldn't turn into objects" doesn't make a lot of sense to me.

Comment: Please see my edit, with an example illustrating perfectly this sentence

Comment: I don't see how this illustrates that sentence; one could wonder though if creating an iterator here is needed and wanted.